# Как сдедать canvas адаптивным?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-canvas

Как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении окна браузера, уменьшался и canvas, при этом, чтобы рисунок не стирался?

Comment: Вот статейка на эту тему https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/143624/

Comment: И здешние варианты - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772957/how-to-make-canvas-responsive

Comment: А самое забавное в этой ситуации что canvas сам по себе адаптивный))) Масло масленное, но в принципе на твой вопрос уже ответили)